# Show styled component more times, based on input param

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have the following component:

```
export const DotSeparator = styled.div<{ nr: number }>`
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border-radius: 3px;
`;
```

There is a way to pass a parameter which multiplies the component? Ex: nr=3 => I would like to see 3 dots shown.

I am not sure how to iterate the content 3 times.

And I would use the styled component this way: `<DotSeparator nr={3} >`

Comment: You can create wrapper component: const Dots = (n: number) => Array(n).fill(null).map(() => <DotSeparator  />)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create component which contan generated dots.

From example below, you can use dots for that you can pass number of dots, also you can use separate dot.

```
interface DotsProps {
  className?: string;
  number: number;
}

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 0.5rem;
`;

export const Dot = styled.div`
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
`;

export const Dots = ({ number, ...rest}: DotsProps): JSX.Element => (
  <Container {...rest}>
    {[...Array(number).keys()].map((_) => (
      <Dot />
    ))}
  </Container>
);

const App = () => <Dots number={33} />;
```